# Get script output to CSV

Tags: 2013, powershell

Please help me to export the output of the script as a CSV.

```
$siteUrl = "https://webapplication"
$daysThreshold = 30  # Number of days to consider as "active"

# Load SharePoint client libraries
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Connect to the site
$web = Get-SPWeb $siteUrl

# Get the user information list
$userInfoList = $web.SiteUserInfoList

# Define the date threshold
$thresholdDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysThreshold)

# Query the list to get active users
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.Query = "<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='Last_x0020_Modified' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>$($thresholdDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))</Value></Geq></Where>"

$items = $userInfoList.GetItems($query)
foreach ($item in $items) {
    Write-Host "User: $($item['Name'])"
}

# Clean up
$web.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not really related to SharePoint but more of a programming question that would be more suited for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

```
$siteUrl = "https://webapplication"
$daysThreshold = 30  # Number of days to consider as "active"

# Load SharePoint client libraries
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Connect to the site
$web = Get-SPWeb $siteUrl

# Get the user information list
$userInfoList = $web.SiteUserInfoList

# Define the date threshold
$thresholdDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysThreshold)

# Query the list to get active users
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.Query = "<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='Last_x0020_Modified' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>$($thresholdDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))</Value></Geq></Where>"

# Create a array to store all objects in
$arr = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]]::new()

$items = $userInfoList.GetItems($query)
foreach ($item in $items) {
    Write-Host "User: $($item['Name'])"
    $arr.add(
        [pscustomobject]@{
            "Name" = $item['Name']
        }
    )
}

# Clean up
$web.Dispose()

# Export to a CSV
$arr | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```